# hide element without setting the display to none in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fold a section of the form without setting its `display` to `none`. If i set the `display` to `none`, the validation is bypassed that is why I don't want to set the `display` to `none`. I know I can set the visibility to `hidden` and `visible` but this solution is not feasible for rendering the view as the space for the folded section stays there. This results in a very odd look of the view with an empty white space with no content on it.

So my question is to hide a section of the html form (without intacting a placeholder for it) without setting its `display` to `none`, so that I could still perform the validation.

Some HTML code:

```
<td style="margin: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid; display:none; overflow: hidden;" colspan="3">
    <div>...</div>
</td>
```

The `display` is initially set to none but once it is unfolded for the first time, I am setting the `height` to 100% and removing the `display` style.

Comment: ...by simply animating a container's height?

Comment: can use jquery hide()

Comment: I tried it but somehow it didn't work... I will update the question with some html code now...

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer `jQuery.hide()` sets `display` to `none`.

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer: it sets the display to none, this is what I want to avoid

Comment: @Upvote MarkAnswer  jquery hide() is display:none

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can move it off the screen:

```
$(elem).css("position", "absolute").css("left", -9999);
```

Or set it's height to 0:

```
$(elem).css("height", 0);
```

Comment: Setting an element's height to '0' it's not enough for `inline` elements

Comment: For setting `height` to `0` the `overflow` should be set to `hidden`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `hidden` is a better option. `auto` could make problems, because it includes the rule to display a scrollbar on overflow. And if this is not handled correctly by the browser for a `height` of `0` it could have negative side effects.

Comment: @ObaidMaroof Good thing I provided an *or* solution :)

Comment: @RGraham: Thanks, great thing that you provided an or solution.. :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to fake `display:none` is by setting the position to absolute (so the element is taken out of flow, no longer influencing the rendering of outside elements) and the visibility to hidden (so it is no longer painted).

```
$(elem).css('visibility', 'hidden').css('position','absolute');
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the opacity of the element to 0.

```
$(elem).css("opacity", 0);
```

Comment: That's like setting `visibility` to `hidden`.

Comment: it doesnt adjust the dom by moving the rest of the content upwards... there remains a white space in the page which for the hidden section

Comment: sorry, i'm not that much good in css, i think this may work here `$(elem).css("text-indent", 9999px);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ele").css({"height" : 0, "width" : 0, "opacity" : 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiding an element with jquery...

```
$('element').addClass('hidden');
```

and in your CSS just use what ever you find appropriate to make that element "hidden"

```
.hidden{
  /* whatever you find appropriate */
}
```

Comment: TzoLy ... do you know what happens to an element if you set `.hide()` ?

Comment: If no, I'll tell you: The element.style `display:none;` is being applied to it. **Edited your answer**.